# NodeList length property always null

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape data for my language learning, vocabulary, etc. I had this code work before in a different laptop (where I coded it). However, I can no longer use that one so I had to copy my files and use a different laptop. Now, after a year or so, I tried to use the code again and I am getting an error that stems from the Length property of my object being null.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Meaning()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim Meaning As Object, tagtype As Object, sentence As Object, lemma As Object
    Dim verb As String, absplit() As String, str As String
    Dim der As String, die As String, das As String
    Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    der = "der"
    die = "die"
    das = "das"

    For Each cell In rng
        'character correction
        verb = cell.Text
        verb = Replace(verb, "ä", "%C3%A4", , , vbBinaryCompare)
        verb = Replace(verb, "ö", "%C3%B6", , , vbBinaryCompare)
        verb = Replace(verb, "ü", "%C3%BC", , , vbBinaryCompare)
        verb = Replace(verb, "ß", "%C3%9F", , , vbBinaryCompare)
        verb = Replace(verb, "Ä", "%C3%84", , , vbBinaryCompare)
        verb = Replace(verb, "Ö", "%C3%96", , , vbBinaryCompare)
        verb = Replace(verb, "Ü", "%C3%9C", , , vbBinaryCompare)
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", "https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=" + verb, False
            .send
            sResponse = .responseText
        End With
    
        With Html
            .body.innerHTML = sResponse
            Set lemma = .querySelector("div.isForeignTerm > div.exact > div.lemma > div > h2.line > span.tag_lemma > a.dictLink")
            Set tagtype = .querySelector("div.isForeignTerm > div.exact > div.lemma > div > h2.line > span.tag_lemma > span.tag_wordtype")
            Set sentence = .querySelectorAll("div.isForeignTerm > div.exact > div.lemma > div > div.lemma_content > div.meaninggroup > div.translation_lines > div.translation > div.example_lines > div.example > span.tag_e > span.tag_s")
            Set Meaning = .querySelectorAll("div.isForeignTerm > div.exact > div.lemma > div > div.lemma_content > div.meaninggroup > div.translation_lines > div.translation > h3.translation_desc > span.tag_trans > a.dictLink")
        End With
        
        With Worksheets(1)
            'lemma
            If lemma Is Nothing Then
            Else
                .Cells(cell.Row, 2) = lemma.innerText
            End If
            
            'Meaning
            If Meaning.Length <= 5 Then
                For i = 0 To Meaning.Length - 1
                    If i < Meaning.Length - 1 Then
                        .Cells(cell.Row, 6 + i) = Meaning(i).innerText + ","
                    Else
                       .Cells(cell.Row, 6 + i) = Meaning(i).innerText
                    End If
                Next i
            Else
                For i = 0 To 4
                    If i < 4 Then
                        .Cells(cell.Row, 6 + i) = Meaning(i).innerText + ","
                    Else
                        .Cells(cell.Row, 6 + i) = Meaning(i).innerText
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
            
            'tagpos
            If tagtype Is Nothing Then
            
            Else
                absplit() = split(tagtype.innerText, ",")
                .Cells(cell.Row, 4) = absplit(0)
            End If
            
            'taggender
            If UBound(absplit()) = 1 And absplit(0) = "noun" Then
                If absplit(1) = " feminine" Then
                    .Cells(cell.Row, 5) = "die"
                ElseIf absplit(1) = " masculine" Then
                    .Cells(cell.Row, 5) = "der"
                ElseIf absplit(1) = " neuter" Then
                    .Cells(cell.Row, 5) = "das"
                ElseIf absplit(1) = " plural" Then
                    .Cells(cell.Row, 5) = "plural"
                    
                End If
            Else
            End If
            
            'sentence
            If sentence.Length <= 5 Then
                For i = 0 To sentence.Length - 1
                    .Cells(cell.Row, 11 + i) = sentence(i).innerText
                Next i
            Else
                For i = 0 To 4
                    .Cells(cell.Row, 11 + i) = sentence(i).innerText
                Next i
            End If
        End With
    Next cell
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

For example, with the word "Zuschuss" in the A2 cell, I'd get an error 91 object variable not set error. Running the code line by line, I noticed that this was due to skipping `If Meaning.Length <=5 Then` since the value is null and going to the Else part of the code, where it needs 5 elements in the NodeList. However, there are only three elements for "Zuschuss" so when it goes for the 4th iteration of the loop, it yields the error. Removing the If Then statement yields an invalid use of null error in the line `For i = 0 To Meaning.Length - 1`. I know that all of this is supposed to work since I still have my flashcard for this word where the code under the If statement successfully ran (last word did not have a comma, whereas with my current run, it would return with a comma, suggesting that there are more elements, i.e. allowance vs allowance,)

I also tried running the first code outlined in [Scraping from VBA with queryselector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735924/scraping-from-vba-with-queryselector) which was confirmed by the poster to work. Still, I'd get an invalid use of null error in the line `For i = 0 To info.Length -1`. It seems like the .Length property is not working properly. Am I missing some references to add? It's been a long time side I coded this so I might have forgotten to add some vital references. I haven't found any similar problems on the internet yet. For reference, my default file had the Microsoft HTML Object Library ticked aside from the default ones. I also tried using Microsoft XML, v3.0 and v6.0, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Where, in the code  (which line), do you get the error 91? The code you posted works successfully on my laptop (for word  "Zuschuss").

Comment: I get the error in the line `.Cells(cell.Row, 6 + i) = Meaning(i).innerText + ","` under `Else For i = 0 To 4 If i < 4 Then` in Meaning. It's because it runs the code in Else instead of the `If Meaning.Length <= 5 Then`, which it is supposed to satisfy

Comment: Maybe the HTMLDocument object (and/or the other objects) needs dereferencing between iterations (set Html=nothing)

Comment: I don't quite get the dereferencing since the error happens within one word, so the HTML doesn't need to be updated yet. I tried creating an integer variable mlength and did `mlength = Meaning.Length` after the Set Meaning = .querySelectorAll.... in With Html. But I still get an error 94 invalid use of null. Somehow, Meaning.Length always gives null instead of the actual (in this case 3). May I ask what references you used when running the code?

Comment: Microsoft HTML Object Library (Location: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.tlb)